# XSD validation for Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xsd, simple-framework

I need to validate an incoming XML against my XSD on Android. I first tried JAXB but found I got Darvik issues. Now I'm planning to use SimpleXML. Can Simple handle validation? If so how?

Also the XSD will reside on the device with the XML and not as a URL.

Comment: SimpleXML relies on [POJO declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001052/android-simple-xml-how-to-declare-a-list-of-elements) of element and attribute types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xerces and native schema validation (in java) in adnroid - you have to download xerces sources and (after some simple manipulations) include it to your own code - you will be able to use DocumentBuilderFactory.setShema method.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142567/xml-schema-validation-xmlsignature-with-xerces-in-android